# FlaskSocketIO - RuntimeError: Working outside of application context. To solve this, set up an application context with app.app_context()

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I got stuck with this issue for 2 days. I tried multiple things but they didn't seem to work for me. I am not able to emit an event.

Main.py -

```
from flask import Flask, g
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'

socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")

@socketio.on('connect')
def handle_connection():
  from notification_handler import Notification_Handler

if __name__ == '__main__':
  server_ip = 'SERVER_IP'
  with app.app_context() :
      socketio.run(app, host=server_ip, port=5000)
```

Notification_Handler.py

```
 from flask import request, g
 from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
 try:
    from __main__ import socketio, app
 except ImportError:
    from application import socketio, app

 class Notification_Handler(object):
    
    @staticmethod
    def store_notification(notification):
       lastnotification = Notification_Handler.fetch_notification()
       resp = {}
       if (lastnotification == None) :
         resp["status"] = False
         resp["message"] = "No notifications available"

       with app.app_context():
          emit('notification_response',resp,namespace='/',broadcast=True)
```

While running, this is the error I am getting -

```
  Working outside of application context.

  This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed to 
  interface with the current application object in some way. To solve
  this, set up an application context with app.app_context().  See the
  documentation for more information.
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/project/release/module/someother.py", line 225, in abc_communication
  Notification_Handler.store_notification(notification)
  File "/home/project/release/module/notification_handler.py", line 73, in store_notification
  emit('notification_response',resp,namespace='/',broadcast=True)
  File "/home/project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_socketio/__init__.py", line 782, in emit
  socketio = flask.current_app.extensions['socketio']
  File "/home/project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 422, in __get__
  obj = instance._get_current_object()
  File "/home/project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 544, in _get_current_object
  return self.__local()  # type: ignore
  File "/home/project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/globals.py", line 52, in _find_app
  raise RuntimeError(_app_ctx_err_msg)
  RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
```

I tried things like using

```
  socketio.emit('notification_response',resp,namespace='/',broadcast=True)
```

as well.

Note - I have a single user, so need to maintain the socket Ids. Also, I am able to connect to flask socket io from Angular socket io. The other files which have **emit** events are working fine, only this file is not working for me.

I am new to python and with socketio.

Edit 1-

**The other file which is working -**

```
 from . notification_handler import Notification_Handler
 import json
 from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
 try:
   from __main__ import socketio
 except ImportError:
   from application import socketio

 Class Notification_Impl(Resource):
   
   @socketio.on('notification_sending_event')
   def get(self):
      notification = Notification_Handler.fetch_notification()
      resp = {}
      if (notification == None) :
        resp["status"] = False
        resp["message"] = "No notifications available"
      else :
        resp["status"] = True
        resp["message"] = json.loads(notification)

      emit('notification_response',resp, namespace='/', broadcast=True)
```

This file doesn't have @staticmethod.

UI Service (Angular) -

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";
import {BASE_URL} from 'src/app/configs/app.config'

@Injectable()
export class SocketService {

  socket:any;

  notificationResponse = new BehaviorSubject({});
  constructor() {

    this.socket = io(BASE_URL+'/');
  }

  listen(event: string){
     return new Observable((subscriber)=>{
        this.socket.on(event, (data)=>{
          subscriber.next(data);
        })
     })
  }

  emit(event:string, data:any){
    this.socket.emit(event, data);
  }
}
```

Component file -

```
  this.socketService.emit('notification_sending_event',{'data':'Connected'});
  this.socketService.listen('notification_response').subscribe((res)=>{
      console.log(res);
  });
```

In **notification_handler.py**, when emit happens, this error occurs, or sometimes UI is not able to listen to it, but when **emit** happens from the other file, the UI listens.

Comment: @miguel Can you please help

Answer (score 2):

You have to create an app context before you call the `emit()` function:

```py
        with app.app_context():
            emit('notification_response', resp, namespace='/', broadcast=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. When I am doing the same thing with other files and using app.app_context inside that, then it works. But not in this file, i.e. Notification_Handler.py. Do I also need to provide namespace in the UI code where I am listening to this event?

Comment: You can't just say "it doesn't work" as that doesn't provide me with any additional information to help you solve the issue. Update your question with the new error that you get when the app context is set up properly as I indicated.

Comment: I have updated the question with the exact things which I wrote.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really see that you are doing this correctly. The updated code, with the app.app_context is broken, there is no `app` being imported, so I suspect you just hand-edited this in the question. The error cannot be the same after you push the context, at the very least the line number of the error should have changed, so you aren't really doing what I'm asking.

Comment: Sorry, the app is imported and the app context is being pushed already as you suggested earlier. Now the error is not there, but emit is not happening as the UI is not able to listen to it.